# Script to redirect to another page if certain content is in the HTML source code?

Tags: javascript, redirect, greasemonkey

I'm looking for a way to create an automatic forwarder (web-browser userscript) if a specific piece of HTML source code matches.

The code `<span class="redux">$STRING</span>` should be searched and if this span class is found and the `$STRING` part matches a certain value the redirect has to be sent.

Unfortunately I'm very bad at web-based scripting, which is why I'm asking here.

An exact HTML snippet I'm looking for would be `<span class="tit">mash</span>`.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for a span with a particular class and a particular value? And can you be sure this span is in the physical source code rather than inserted by JavaScript post-DOM load?

Comment: I'm pretty much stuck at the beginning. document.getElementsByTagName('span'), doesn't really help me, since it's not static enough to go for an indexed element.

Comment: @Marzipan It's what I'm looking for, but you're right. I don't know this for sure. Thanks for the hint, I'm going to check that.

Comment: Post exact snippets of the code JS and/or HTML that you are looking for.

Comment: @BrockAdams an exact HTML snippet I'm looking for would be
<span class="tit">mash</span>

Comment: `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tit");for(var i in x){ if (x[i].innerText == "mash"){ document.location="new-url.com";}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answers have espoused jQuery, which is no bad thing. If for any reason you want to do this natively, here's two approaches (one if you need to support older browsers, one using newer JS).

**Method 1 (works in older browsers)**

```
window.onload = function() {

    var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

    for (var i=0, len=spans.length; i<len; i++) {
        if (/\bsome_class\b/.test(spans[i].className) && spans[i].innerHTML == look_for_value) {
            location.replace('some/redirect.php');
        break;
        }
    }

};
```

**Method 2 (newer browsers)**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.body.querySelectorAll('.some_class'), function(el) {
        if (el.innerHTML == 'some value') {
            location.replace('some/redirect.php');
            return;
        }
    });
}, false);
```

One advantage of the latter is it uses the newer DOMContentLoaded event, which is preferable in this case (whereas onload waits for images and other assets to load before firing).

[EDIT - as Brock points out, `location.replace()` overwrites the history entry for the current page. With some redirects (most?) this is what you want, but not necessarily. If not, use `location.href = ...` instead.]

Comment: `location.replace()` overwrites the history, which may be a bad thing in this case.

Comment: Depends on the nature of the redirect. 50/50, I'd say. I'll edit the answer to point out the option here.

Comment: Side note: neither `onload` nor `DOMContentLoaded` are necessary in a default Greasemonkey script (Firefox).  Nor are they reliable in a default Chrome userscript.  The rest of the answer is serviceable, except that `textContent` should be used instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions. For some reason Firebug returns "undefined" for all methods you listed (innerText, textContent, innerHTML) which is apparently the problem, everything else works as it should now.

Comment: What version of Firefox? There's no way it could return undefined for innerHTML provided you were checking it on a real element, as that property has existed forever. textContent is newer, hence I gave you both a legacy approach and one for newer browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to select classes:

```
if($(".YourClass").length() > 0) {
    window.location = "redirectURL.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague, but here's a general approach for redirecting when specific contents are found.  It uses the awesome power of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Redirect on specfic contents
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var redirectURL = "http://xkcd.com/870/";
var triggerStr  = "Buy more beer!";     // Regex allowed.

/*--- Extend jQuery with a case-insensitive version of contains().
    Also allows regular expressions.
*/
jQuery.extend (
    jQuery.expr[':'].containsCI = function (a, i, m) {
        //--- The next is faster than jQuery(a).text()...
        var sText   = (a.textContent || a.innerText || "");     
        var zRegExp = new RegExp (m[3], 'i');

        return zRegExp.test (sText);
    }
);

//--- The following selector depends mightily on exact page details!
var targetTextNode  = $('div span.redux:containsCI(' + triggerStr + ')');
if (targetTextNode.length) {
    document.location   = redirectURL;
}
```